# Need to make a new column queryable

Tags: sql

I created the column `frfpost_short` but now I am having trouble making the column usable in a query.

```
select t.corridor,
s.corridor_code_rb,t.roadway,s.SVYLENG2012,
round(cast(t.frfpost as float),3)) as frfpost_short,
s.FRFPOST,s.BEG_GN
from SEC_FILE_IMPORT_2014 t,NORTH_VAN_DATA_VIEW_MOD_032015 s,
where frfpost_short = s.FRFPOST -- This line is causing problems
                                -- I would like to make frfpost_short queryable
and t.corridor = s.CORRIDOR_CODE
order by 1
```

Comment: PL-SQL says that frfpost_short is an invalid identifier. I mean to say that's where the error is found in the query.

Comment: You can not refer to an alias in `where` clause inside the same `select` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery or repeat the expression.  Aliases defined in the `select` are not available in the `where`:

```
select t.corridor,
       s.corridor_code_rb,t.roadway, s.SVYLENG2012,
       round(cast(t.frfpost as float), 3) as frfpost_short,
       s.FRFPOST, s.BEG_GN
from SEC_FILE_IMPORT_2014 t join
     NORTH_VAN_DATA_VIEW_MOD_032015 s
     on round(cast(t.frfpost as float), 3) = s.FRFPOST and
        t.corridor = s.CORRIDOR_CODE
order by 1
```

I fixed your query.  In particular, learn to use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: what's the meaning of order by 1? from what I know it's meaningless. am I wrong?

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . The question is more appropriately directly at the OP, because is it in the original query.  The use of numbers in `order by` is an older-style SQL.  The `1` refers to the first column, in this case, `t.corridor`.  The only database that I know of that does not support this logic is Hive, but I think the syntax is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I thought it's better to ask you since your reputation (and the answers I've seen you give to people) suggest you really know your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aliases in `where` clause, you need to use below solution

```
select t.corridor,
s.corridor_code_rb,t.roadway,s.SVYLENG2012,
round(cast(t.frfpost as float),3)) as frfpost_short,
s.FRFPOST,s.BEG_GN
from SEC_FILE_IMPORT_2014 t,NORTH_VAN_DATA_VIEW_MOD_032015 s,
where round(cast(t.frfpost as float),3)) = s.FRFPOST 
and t.corridor = s.CORRIDOR_CODE
order by 1
```